# Is it possible to have multiple different tracks with the same MAX for Live device?

Tags: midi, ableton-live

I want to visualize the different tracks with Images in max for live device according to the parts of a drumset. But I can't seem to have the same max for live device for all the Ableton tracks. Is there maybe a way to do this? Thanks.

[image]

I tried apply the different midi notes from Ableton to Max for live to showcase a different image with every instrument. Only it will only work for the track the max for live device is in.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't get MIDI from different tracks in a Max device that is on a single track, which is what you seem to be after judging from the screen shot. As a workaround, you could add a device on each track that sends its incoming MIDI to the single device where you want to visualize the notes. You'd use send and receive objects (without the `---` prefix to keep things local to the device).

Another approach would be to add your visualisation Max MIDI effect device on the drum group track instead of a single track. That way, you should get all MIDI notes that go to your drum track into your device.

Comment: Thanks for understanding and giving solutions. I don't really get what you mean with "You'd use send and receive objects (without the --- prefix to keep things local to the device)." How do you keep the Midi inputs from every track to one patcher? I tried copying the different patches on one main patch but that didn't work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is some information about the `---` prefix [here](https://docs.cycling74.com/max8/refpages/send#name).

Did you try the other approach too, adding your device on the Group track instead of a single drum track?